# problems with getting data for dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a dropdownlist   getting data from data base

it  contains 4 data :

my  controller   :

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {        
        ViewBag.Postes = _db.Postes.ToList();           
        return View();

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index( Poste poste,string num_cin="R346399")
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (poste.Id == 3)
            {
            return RedirectToAction("Inscription", "Candidat");
            }

        return View(poste);


          }

      }
```

my  view

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id,
        new SelectList(ViewBag.Postes, "Id", "intitule_poste"),"choisir le poste")
```

the   problem  that  if  i  choose a value  from  dropdownlist  that  !=3    it's give me an error   "that  items must be not null "

Comment: Are you using view model in your view?
if yes then try 
new SelectList(Model.postes, "Id", "intitule_poste"),"choisir le poste")

Comment: i'm not using a ViewModel....

Comment: On which line do you have the error and what is the exact message?

Comment: Please show us your entire view. If you don't have a ViewModel how can you set `model => model.Id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You view includes `@Html.DropDownListFor()` which is generated based on the value of `ViewBag.Postes`. When you return the view (i.e. when poste.Id is not equal to 3) you must reassign the value of `ViewBag.Postes`

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
  if (poste.Id == 3)
  {
    return RedirectToAction("Inscription", "Candidat");
  }
  ViewBag.Poste = _db.Postes.ToList(); // reassign collection for dropdown
  return View(poste);
}
```